# Python Dataframe subtract value from one column from each list element of another column of a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe. Column one has a list of numbers. Second column has average of list of numbers in column one. I need to create third column such that I subtract mean value from each of the elements of column one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[4.2,2.3,6.5,2.3],[4.1,5.3,6.5,3.8]]})
df['avg'] = df['A'].apply(lambda p: np.average(p))
df['a_avg' = df['A'].apply(lambda p: (np.array(p)-df['avg']).to_list())
```

Expected output:

```
df
           A               avg           a_avg
0     [4.2,2.3,6.5,2.3]   3.825        [0.375, -1.525, 2.675, -1.525]
1     [4.1,5.3,6.5,3.8]   4.925        [-0.825, 0.375, 1.575, -1.125]
```

I created column two for my clarity. if there is a way we can directly get column three from column one, that is also good. whats wrong with the code i have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with convert lists to numpy for improve performance:

```
df['a_avg'] = [(np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist() for p in df['A']]
```

Or:

```
df['a_avg'] = df.A.apply(lambda p: (np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist())
   
print (df)
                      A                           a_avg
0  [4.2, 2.3, 6.5, 2.3]  [0.375, -1.525, 2.675, -1.525]
1  [4.1, 5.3, 6.5, 3.8]  [-0.825, 0.375, 1.575, -1.125]
```

Vectorized solution working if each list has same length:

```
arr = np.array(df.A.tolist()) 
df['a_avg'] = np.round(arr - np.average(arr), 3).tolist()
   
print (df)
                      A                            a_avg
0  [4.2, 2.3, 6.5, 2.3]  [-0.175, -2.075, 2.125, -2.075]
1  [4.1, 5.3, 6.5, 3.8]   [-0.275, 0.925, 2.125, -0.575]
```

**Testing performance**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[4.2,2.3,6.5,2.3],[4.1,5.3,6.5,3.8]]})

#2k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


#Timeless solution 
In [36]: %timeit df["a_avg"] = [[round(e - np.average(lst), 3) for e in lst] for lst in df["A"]]
118 ms ± 659 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
In [37]: %timeit df['a_avg'] = [(np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist() for p in df['A']]
37.1 ms ± 162 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit df['a_avg'] = df.A.apply(lambda p: (np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist())
37.7 ms ± 446 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [39]: %%timeit
    ...: arr = np.array(df.A.tolist()) 
    ...: df['a_avg'] = np.round(arr - np.average(arr), 3).tolist()
    ...: 
1.36 ms ± 46.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

**Testing in 20k rows**

```
#20k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [41]: %timeit df["a_avg"] = [[round(e - np.average(lst), 3) for e in lst] for lst in df["A"]]
1.18 s ± 5.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [42]: %timeit df['a_avg'] = [(np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist() for p in df['A']]
366 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [43]: %timeit df['a_avg'] = df.A.apply(lambda p: (np.round(np.array(p) - np.average(p), 3)).tolist())
364 ms ± 824 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: arr = np.array(df.A.tolist()) 
    ...: df['a_avg'] = np.round(arr - np.average(arr), 3).tolist()
    ...: 
    ...: 
13.7 ms ± 111 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Both the solutions worked. Thank you.

Comment: @SNB - Are same length lists?

Comment: @SNB - Perfromance is not important? Because solution is slow from Timeless.

Comment: @SNB - only one answer should be accepted, not both.

Comment: Length of the lists are same. Yes. Both the solutions are making the program very slow as i have around 1024 elements in each list. Also i have 500 rows of data. is there a better solution?

Comment: @SNB Use solution bellow `Vectorized solution working if each list has same length:`

Answer (score 3):

> ..if there is a way we can **directly get column three from column one**,
> that is also good.

I would do it this way :

```
df["a_avg"] = [[round(e - np.average(lst), 3) for e in lst] for lst in df["A"]]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                      A                           a_avg
0  [4.2, 2.3, 6.5, 2.3]  [0.375, -1.525, 2.675, -1.525]
1  [4.1, 5.3, 6.5, 3.8]  [-0.825, 0.375, 1.575, -1.125]
```

Comment: This solution works fine. Time cost is higher.